# What are methods available to connect two arduino

Tags: arduino

I have two bluetooth HC-6 module and two Arduino UNO board. I want to connect these two arduino module using these bluetooth module. Can i connect?

Comment: Typically you need one as a master (HC-05) and the other as slave (HC-06 or HC-05)

Answer (score 0):

HC-06 is a Slave only device, which means that you can connect your smartphone to it to send and get data, but itself can not act as a Master. You need at least one module that can act as Master, such as HC-05.

Note that HC-06 looks physically just like the HC-05, and not necessairly cheaper, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

One connected to a HC-05 zs-040 and one connected to a HC-06 zs-040.

The HC-05 has a connection from pin 34 to +3.3v. This activates “full” AT mode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgMKj.jpg)